# How to send username and password in api body in react native?

Tags: react-native, fetch-api

I want to send username and password in my body, but in api get null and showing me message : "Field are required. Api is created in php.

```
const [Email, SetEmail] = useState('');
const [Password, SetPassword] = useState('');

const SendLogin = (props) => {
    console.log(Email, Password)
    fetch(".......", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "username": Email,
            "password": password
        })
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        })
}
```

Comment: you were passing  password as small p in your body change it as Password that is capital P

Comment: On in api small p is there

Comment: "password": password iam talking about the value password you were declaring it as Password but using it as password

Comment: your right, i have change it, but same error is there

Comment: Have you checked whether your API is working correctly by postman are you getting your correct values here console.log(Email, Password)

Comment: on console.log(Email, Password)  getting my value but  in body is null and in postman working properly can you help me via anydesk or teamviewer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212918/discussion-between-raj-shah-and-user12129132).

Comment: Any update on this issue?